# Google Cloud SQL data loss

Tags: google-cloud-sql, data-loss

I have recently started using google cloud sql as the backend for an api. Today whilst adding a new IP to the access control the DB went down. I restarted it after a while and when it came back up several tables of data had been lost.

I have it set to use the more reliable method for writes and cannot see how this could happen.

How is this possible?

Comment: I think that may be a question for Google Cloud's technical support staff.

Comment: Can you please write to cloud-sql@google.com about this and indicate the instance name?

Comment: I have just emailed them, thank you. Do you know what their response time is like? I can start manually recovering the DB but don't want to touch it if it's going to make it less likely that Google can recover it from their end.

Comment: Thanks Joachim, I tried that route first but Google's supprt specifically states to post the issue here with the tag google-cloud-sql. I didn;t have any contact details until Razvan just posted them.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about google cloud tech support

Answer (score 2):

It could be you are using the wrong storage engine. You should use InnoDB. The Google Cloud SQL FAQ states:

> Warning: Using the MyISAM storage engine could result in data loss in some situations, such as unclean shutdowns. For more information, Corrupted MyISAM Tables.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/faq#innodb